# Matching CSS comments in Regexp

Tags: css, ruby, regex, comments

I got this Regexp:

```
/(\/\*[\w\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)/g
```

I'd like to match single line comments, and multi lines comments with or without special characters.

So, this get matched:

```
/* hey ! */

/*
  ho
*/
```

But this doesn't (and I'd like this to get matched too) :

```
/* hey ! */

/*
  = ho
*/

/* line 3, ../../../app/assets/stylesheets/v3/reset.scss */
```

I tried many things, to no avail. Including replacing `\w` by `\W`, I'm out of ideas.

**Live example:** https://www.regex101.com/r/jV0dV1/2

Answer (score 1):

```
\/\*[^\*\/]*\*\/
```

`/*` followed by any character(s) other than `*/`, followed by `*/`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/\*(?:(?!\*/).|\n)*\*/
```

[regex101 demo.](https://www.regex101.com/r/zK6pD0/1)

---

Explanation:

```
/\*  literal /*
(?:
    (?! if the next characters aren't */
        \*/
    )
    .   consume the next character
|
    \n  also consume newlines, which the dot doesn't match
)*  ...as often as possible
\*/  literal */
```